# Comparing columns in two different excel sheets and workbooks, then posting the matching value into another column

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm having lots of trouble trying to figure out this macro, so right now I'm using 2 sheets in a workbook; I'd like to use two different workbooks but that isn't as important as the issue.

To explain, Sheet1 column E is the id number and in Sheet2 column A is the id number, now if any value in Sheet1 E matches a value in column A in Sheet2, I need the macro to copy the corresponding cell from Sheet 2 column D. So essentially if E5 (from sheet 1) matched A1 in Sheet2, I would need the macro to output Sheet2's D1 to Sheet1's F5.  It would also be nice to delete the values of Sheet1 column F if Sheet1 column E doesn't match a value in Sheet 2 column A.

I have some code but it just pastes the values from Sheet2's column D if a value of Sheet1 column E matches a value from Sheet2 column A. The problem is when the values pasted from Sheet2 are pasted in Sheet1's column F and the values aren't matched with the correct value that it matched with in Sheet2. They are just dumbed. So if Sheet1 column E was like this

```
Sheet1 Column E    Sheet1 F

1317               relays_120x120.jpg
1319              Control%20boards_120x120
1320              Control%20boards_120x120

Sheet2 Column A             Sheet2 column D
1317                       relays_120x120
1318                       /relays_120x120
1319                    ebay/SingleRunOval
```

But in reality I need them all to be equal and if Sheet1 column E has a value that isnt in Sheet2 column, then dont post a link in Sheet1 column F leave it blank.

Here is the code I have

```
Sub FindMatches()

    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    For oldRow = 2 To 1170
        For newRow = 1 To 1170
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, 1) Then

                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(oldRow, 4)


                i = i + 1

                Exit For
            End If
        Next newRow
    Next oldRow


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could accomplish your goal with the VLookup function. Add this formula to Sheet1 F1: `=IFERROR(VLookup(E1,Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE),"")`

That formula will copy the cell into sheet1 if a match is found, but if no match is found the cell will remain blank.

Comment: how can I macro it in to using a vlookup(value(e1,Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE) instead of returning a blank

Comment: What do you want it to return instead of a blank cell?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below code. I have just modified your code using StrComp function

```
Sub FindMatches()

    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For oldRow = 1 To 1170
        For newRow = 1 To 1170
            If StrComp((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, 5).Text), (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, 1).Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                i = oldRow
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = " "
                Else
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, 4)
                i = i + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next newRow
    Next oldRow

End Sub
```