# Using List options in the sheet and filtering the criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, Sheet1 is the database sheet and sheet2 is the input sheet.

With the database sheet of column A I have the ID.

With the input sheet I have the Column B with ID. I have a dropdown list created in each cell and each column. I populated the list by "Data Validation".

I would like to know, if it is possible, I can select a ID in column B of Input sheet. and it shows the corresponding results in the row. For eg : if I am  filling in the Column B then according to the column B (ID), column A , C, D, E should be filled automatically.

The column arrangements in both the sheets are not same. but the header name is the same.

Could anyone help with this critical issue. Thanking you in advance

EDIT:

```
Sub DEMO()
Dim srcLastRow As Long, destLastRow As Long
Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set srcWS = Sheets("DataBase")
Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
srcLastRow = srcWS.Cells(srcWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
destLastRow = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To destLastRow
For j = 5 To srcLastRow
If destWS.Cells(i, "B").Value = srcWS.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
destWS.Cells(i, "A") = srcWS.Cells(j, "B")
destWS.Cells(i, "C") = srcWS.Cells(j, "C")
destWS.Cells(i, "D") = srcWS.Cells(j, "D")
destWS.Cells(i, "E") = srcWS.Cells(j, "E")
destWS.Cells(i, "F") = srcWS.Cells(j, "f")
destWS.Cells(i, "G") = srcWS.Cells(j, "G")
destWS.Cells(i, "H") = srcWS.Cells(j, "H")
destWS.Cells(i, "I") = srcWS.Cells(j, "I")
End If
Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have this code working. but I would like to have it with worksheet_Change. When I tried the same with worksheet_Change , its giving an stackoverflow error.
and the excel stops responding.

EDIT: 
[image: This is how my datasheet looks. the items are repeated multiple time .but in the input sheet, I have the list, in such a way that only highlighted part is considered.]
[image: this is how I would like to have my input sheet. when I click on column B with ID, it should copy the corresponding row details]

Comment: @ScottCraner is it going to be closed now ?

Comment: @ScottCraner I could not find anything related to my issue,, And that's why I have this blank post with no code. I am sorry for that. but I dint get an idea to proceed and that's why I asked in the forum

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882516/comparing-columns-in-two-different-excel-sheets-and-workbooks-then-posting-the?rq=1

Comment: @Jenny how big is your database. You may use `worksheet_change` event to do this but this might become slower when the data is more

Comment: @GowthamShiva Thank you that you responded to my issue. I want to have Worksheet_Change . My database contains 200 rows.

Comment: @GowthamShiva I have the abve code in the edit working as I want. But I would like to have that in my worksheet_Change

Comment: @Jenny did you try wrapping everything inside a worksheet_change ?

Comment: When you put it in a worksheet change event you need to turn the events off before making any changes to the worksheet via the code, and turn it back on after making the changes: `Application.EnableEvents = False` False is off.  Make sure you turn it back on.

Comment: @ yeah, I did that way. Just removing the sub demo() and replacing it with worksheet_Change

Comment: The error you are getting is due to the fact that each change causes the event to e called again and it creates a loop that will crash Excel.

Comment: So, how do I rectify it ?

Comment: See my other comment about turning off the events temporarily.

Comment: I tried it,and it dint give me any result

Comment: @Jenny can you post some sample data too?

Comment: @GowthamShiva ok. I will post some data for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code refactored to fit into a worksheet_change event.  This code would go into the code for the `Input` worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim srcRow As Long
Dim chgRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim srcWS As Worksheet

Set srcWS = Sheets("DataBase")

Set chgRng = Intersect(Me.Range("B:B"), Target)
If Not chgRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In chgRng
        srcRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            srcRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, srcWS.Range("A:A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If srcRow > 0 Then
            On Error GoTo GetOut
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.Cells(rng.Row, "A").Value = srcWS.Cells(srcRow, "B").Value
            Me.Range(Me.Cells(rng.Row, "C"), Me.Cells(rng.Row, "I")).Value = srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(srcRow, "C"), srcWS.Cells(srcRow, "I")).Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next rng
End If

GetOut:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not getting my result. Nothing happens with my sheet

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Sub DEMO()
Dim srcLastRow As Long, destLastRow As Long
Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, n As Long
Dim vDB, rngDB As Range, vData

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set srcWS = Sheets("DataBase")
Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

srcLastRow = srcWS.Cells(srcWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
destLastRow = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

vData = srcWS.Range("a5").CurrentRegion

With destWS
    Set rngDB = .Range("a2", "h" & destLastRow)
    vDB = rngDB
End With
n = UBound(vDB, 1)
For i = 1 To n
    For j = 2 To UBound(vData, 2)
        If vDB(i, 2) = vData(j, 1) Then
            vDB(i, 1) = vData(j, 2)
            For k = 3 To 8
                vDB(i, k) = vData(j, k)
            Next k
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
rngDB = vDB
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```